Spark Scala set max based on previous value in the same column and also group by
I am trying to achieve the below shown result. In spark Scala, I would like to set the max value based on the previous value in the same column and another column.
Source Data Frame:

Final Result:

In the image pasted, I would like to achieve the result of maxValFinal. We already have the Data frame result with column maxVal.
maxValFinal logic:
The grouping is based on TypeId, order by TypeId and BandType. So, the resulting MaxValFinal will Increase/Decrease based on the sorting - TypeId, BandType.
If
the current maxVal < 100 then maxValFinal value will be 100
else
Condition 1 (Previous maxValFinal(lag) is null):
maxFinal value will be current maxVal

Condition 2 (Previous maxValFinal(lag) is not null):
 Compare the current MaxVal with previous value of maxValFinal, 
   if the previous value of maxValFinal > current value of maxVal, 
     then previous value of maxValFinal 
   else current value of maxVal

I tried withColumn using lag function, but it simply fetches the previous value of maxVal for each current maxVal. I am unable to compare the maxValFinal previous value in the same column while deriving it.
If someone could help me with the login in Spark scala that would be great.
Thank you so much in advance.
I have now achieved this in a complex way by adding two more columns using withColumn as shown below:

  val window = Window.partitionBy(col("TypeId")).orderBy("TypeId","BandType")

  dfFinal = sourceDF.withColumn("maxRounded",
    when(col("maxVal") < 100, 100)
      .otherwise(col("maxVal")))
  .withColumn("maxLag", when (col("maxRounded") > lag(col("maxRounded"), 1).over(window),col("maxRounded"))
    .otherwise(lag(col("maxRounded"), 1).over(window)))
  .withColumn("maxValFinal",
    when(col("TypeId").isin(1,8),
      when(col("maxLag").isNotNull,
        when(col("maxLag") > lag(col("maxLag"),1).over(window),col("maxLag"))
          .otherwise(
            when(lag(col("maxLag"),1).over(window).isNotNull, lag(col("maxLag"),1).over(window))
              .otherwise(col("maxRounded"))))
    .otherwise(col("maxRounded")))
  .otherwise(col("maxRounded")))

